# Does Mr. X reveal his location on every turn of the travel log that is circled?

Tags: scotland-yard

When playing the board game Scotland Yard, does Mr. X reveal his location on every turn of the travel log that is circled? Or does he hide his location on every circled turn of the travel log and reveal it for all other turns?

Comment: Is there a reason why you suspect it is the latter?  Because it definitely isn't, and the game would be very short and unsatisfying if you tried to play it that way...

Comment: @Southpaw Hare : In that case, should you not edit his question so that only 1 question is asked instead of 2 questions?

Comment: @RobertMiller The issue is not the number of questions being asked, but rather, that I think this question(s) are on the borderline of being too simple or showing no research effort.  It's essentially the basic premise of the game.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mr X. **reveals** his current location on, and only on, the **circled turns**, or at any time he is on the same space as a police player (in which case he immediately loses the game and the police players win the game).  All remaining turns (the majority) are played as hidden information.

Keep in mind that if Mr. X uses a *Double Move Token* to skip over a reveal turn, **Mr. X must still reveal where he was at that time** even though he is no longer there.  For this reason as well as convenience, it is a common house rule to leave the Mr. X token on his "last known location" at the last time of reveal.